# adding a text editor to a swt List widget

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

In the eclipse plugin I am working on, I want to make editable the content of a List (org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List). However, most of the examples I have found show only how to add an  item editor to either a swt Table or a Tree. Is it possible to do the same with a list ?, or should I try to replace my list with a single column table ?.
This is how I instantiate the list:

```
new List (theComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use JFace's `TableViewer` and `CellEditor`s? That's much easier and it already does a lot of stuff for you. You only need to hide the headers and use only a single column, as you already pointed out. Then it should look like a List.